# PageLoad not called in Sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a number of pages with custom harepoint visual web parts.  In the page load of these web parts, i am doing some logic which i need to trigger every time the page loads.  the problem is that when i use the browser back button, or javascript, to redirect the user to the previous page, the pageload is not being invoked.  it seems like the page is being retrieved from a cache.  can this be disabled easily?  is there any other workaround to ensure that the code fires every time the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the back button will load from cache, you are correct in that.

To disable cache, you need to set an "expires" = -1 meta tag in the head section of the page but this seems a bit drastic in order to fire logic for a page.

I'd suggest using the jQuery document ready approach rather than page load. This will fire regardless of where the page information is loaded from.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Insert code here

});
```